# Is there a way to get all digits after decimals in python?

Tags: python-3.x

I am having a trouble with sum of decimal digits. How can I take the digits that are after the decimal point using recursion? I have written the code for adding digits of a number like this:

```py
def sumd2(n):
    s = 0
    while n:
        s += n % 10
        n //= 10
    return s
```

Now, I want to get all the digits after decimal point to be an integer like `1.234` to `234`.

Comment: you can take the input float as a string, and then split `.` from it and then treat LHS (pure integer part) and RHS(floating part) separately

Comment: Is using recursion a prerequisite? You can get a similar solution by recursing something like `n = n - int(n); n = n * 10` to get decimal digits, but you will run into truncation issues (results like `0.12345999999999`). It's a better idea to either use a string representation to split up the number and get all the digits, or look into the [decimal](https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html) module.

Comment: Instead of dividing by 10, try multiplying by 10. Also, your current example is not recursion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can consider this as a string and split it by '.' and then take the second element of the list.Convert back to int. After you get the number after decimal point, you can apply your logic to get the sum.

```
a=0.345
a= str(a)
a= int(a.split('.')[1])
sumd2(a)
```